# Pulling dimension from another fact table in SSRS Dax query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, dax

I have two fact tables. I would like to pull columns from a dimension which is part of another fact table using Dax query. The table is coming from a tabular cube. So far I have tried:

```
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZE(
        'vwFCML'
        ,'Vessel'[VName]
        ,'Port'[PCountry]
        ,'PO'[Type]
    )
```

Vessel[VName] and Port[PCountry] dimensions are from the vwFCML fact table while the PO[Type] is from another fact table called OrdTable. I get the error

```
The column 'Type' specified in the 'SUMMARIZE' function was not found in the input table
```

I am new to dax and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a table called PO with a column called Type? Did you rename database table `OrdTable` to `PO` in your tabular data model?

Comment: Yes I do have a table called PO with the column called Type. That table is linked to another fact table called OrdTable, it's joined to that table using a key. Please let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: At this stage can only suggest troubleshooting options, like for example, add and remove arguments from the SUMMARIZE function and see which columns work and which don't

Comment: I tried using SUMMARIZECOLUMNS and it seemed to work. But some values on my columns are not changing, it's like they are repeated. Is there a way to join the fact table vwFCML and OrdTable in summarize using a common dimension? so I can pull other dimensions that are connected to vwFCML and those connected to OrdTable.

Comment: I'm not sure and I've never done it, because you should really define your dimensions at a lower level than this. Sorry I can't help further, I suggest continuing to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens if the table listed in summarize section has no relation to other tables.

In your case, there is a possibility that the `vwFCML` table has no relation with `PO` table.

If you have another table, e.g. `Dim_Vessel` that is somehow linked to both `vwFCML` and `PO`, try using that as the summarize table (even if you are not using any column from that table at all). 
e.g.

```
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Dim_Vessel'
        ,'Vessel'[VName]
        ,'Port'[PCountry]
        ,'PO'[Type]
        ,....

    )
```

Hope this make some sense?

Comment: That is absolutely right, vwFCML table does not have any relation with PO table, but the other fact table OrdTable does. However, both vwFCML table and OrdTable does have a relation with Port table. So I was hoping of forming a relationship between the two Fact tables through its common dimension Port, that way I could use the PO table.

Comment: Did you try using `Port` table as the first table in the `SUMMARIZE` section?

Comment: I tried using Port as the first table, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe you need to revisit the diagram of your Tabular model. There must be some parent table or a table that link to all of your required output fields. Otherwise, you may need to use some custom solution like UNION etc.

Comment: Pretty much an easier way to explain is, The fact table vwFCML is the parent to a bunch of other dimension tables including PO. The fact table OrdTable is also the parent to other dimension tables including PO. So vwFCML is connected to PO and OrdTable is connected to PO. However I need dimensions A, B, C and D that are connected to vwFCML and also dimensions E, F, G, H that are connected to OrdTable. I just there is a way to join the two Fact tables using PO as the common dimension. If I used PO as the primary table, I cannot access dimension A, B, ..., G, H. I hope that clarifies things.